# Capturar dados de todos elementos select's no HTML com Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Fiz um `ngFor` para listar elementos `select` HTML e estou querendo capturar todos os dados selecionados por esse `select`... fiz da seguinte forma:

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
    <div *ngFor="let data of getSizeArray(dataHead); let i = index" class="example-box cursor-normal">
        <select formControlName="objetoMapeado">
            <option *ngFor="let d of displayedColumns" [ngValue]="d">
                {{d}}
            </option>
        </select>   
    </div>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
public displayedColumns: string[] = 
        ['Nota Fiscal','Fornecedor','Data da Compra','Valor da Compra','Numero de Parcela','Valor da Parcela','Tipo de Recebimento'];

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        objetoMapeado: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Problema que quando faço um `console.log` ele só exibe o valor do primeiro elemento e não de todos os elementos `select` HTML.

```
console.log(this.secondFormGroup.get('objetoMapeado').value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso vc tem que usar formArray inves do group

```
  this.formArray =  new FormArray(
  this.data.map(value=> new FormControl(value)) // os dados que seu array é baseado, é bem ruim chamar uma função no html como vc ta fazendo
 //passar o valor é opicional
);
```

no html

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of mappedArray; let i = index" class="example-box cursor-normal">
        <select [control]="formArray[i]">
            <option *ngFor="let d of displayedColumns" [ngValue]="d">
                {{d}}
            </option>
        </select>   
    </div>
```

Comment: Não entendi como funcionaria a implementação no `application.components.ts`

Comment: Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. <select [control]="formArray[i]">

Comment: então vc tem que fazer o map com base no array que vc ta fazendo o for

Comment: Como ficaria ? Não tenho mta xp com Angular